# Deployment with Eclipse, Git and Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there a way to specify if the java source files are included in the WAR file when deploying through eclipse?

Please consider the following scenarios:

1. Using export to war: This is simple and straight forward. If you check the check box marked "Export source files", then the source files are included in the WAR.
2. Publishing to the local Tomcat server: The source files are never included in the wtpwebapps directory and there is no WAR file. Again, simple.
3. Publishing to Elastic Beanstalk through the eclipse AWS toolkit on a Windows machine: The source files are ALWAYS included with the WAR file (which is exploded into the git folder and then deployed as a Zip file).
4. Publishing to Elastic Beanstalk through the eclipse AWS toolkit on a Linux (Ubuntu) machine: The source files are NEVER included with the WAR file which is eventually deployed.

I have not found a way to stop the source files from being included in 3 or include them in 4. This may well NOT be an OS issue, but a simple setting in some configuration file that is set differently on the two machines. Or it could be the way the plug-ins were written for the two Operating Systems (are plug-ins OS specific?). Even if that's the case, is there a setting where it can be changed?

I tried playing with the Web Deployment Assembly settings, but couldn't figure out how to make that work as far as source is concerned.

Any insight you may have into this will help.